# Why can't I add a new term to a Dictionary?

Tags: error-handling

```
elif choice == "2":
    print("These are terms stored in the dictionary so far: ")
    for i in values_so_far:
        print(i)
    term = input("\nWhat term do you want me to add?: ")
    if term not in Dictionary:
        definition = input("\nWhat's the definition?: ")
        Dictionary[term] = definition
        print("\n",term,"has been added")
        Dictionary.append[term]
        values_so_far.append[term]
    else:
        print("\nThat term already exists! Try redefining it [option: 3]")
```

Produces the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Flynn\Desktop\programs\Programming Dictionary.py", line 98, in 
        Dictionary.append[term]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0):

The line `Dictionary[term] = definition` already added the key value pair associating `term` and `definition` to your dictionary.  `append` is not a method that is defined for dictionaries.

More on dictionaries:

Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries